# MCP9600 not changing thermocouple type setting

Tags: embedded, adc

I run 4 MCP9600s on ESP32 and experience a problem with setting the TC type.

I tried hard to post the code here according to the rules using the code toolbar button and the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut and '''
''' but nothing worked. In the code I set the TK type to type K in for loop for 4 sensores and than put out  Serial prints about it. (I quoted the code [here][1]).

and this is the output:

Thermocouple 0 type set to K type
Thermocouple 1 type set to K type
Thermocouple 2 type set to S type
Thermocouple 4 type set to R type

S.O.S.
P.S. I also have no idea how did 'i' hit 4.
P.S. I asked this question on Adafruit forum before, but I'm not getting it answered probably due to using costom design board.

[1]: https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=185566#:~:text=of%20the%20code%3A-,CODE%3A%20SELECT%20ALL%20%7C%20TOGGLE%20FULL%20SIZE,-for%20(i%20%3D%200

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by changing I2C Clock frequency from 100 to 25 kHz.
(In my case by adding  `Wire.setClock(25000);` after `Wire.begin();` (In my case after `mcp.begin();`).